# split string number to be 2 each strings in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, loops, split

how to split a string number to be arrays
example :

```
var str = "124590"
var str2 = "12459010"

// output:
["12", "45", "90"]
["12", "45", "90", "10"];
```

and how to make those array strings to be number also in the array, 
and if we use regex, could it work? thx

Comment: If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just [edit] the question and add the relevant parts of your code into it, because without that we cannot help. Also please see **[ask]**.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this to split it every 2 characters:

```js
var str = "124590";
var str2 = "12459010";

let regex = /\d{2}/g;
let array = str.match(regex);
let array2 = str2.match(regex);

console.log(array);
console.log(array2);
```

`\d` matches any digit, `{2}` makes sure it matches twice. The `g` part makes sure it matches every occurance and doesn't stop at the first match.

Answer (score 0):

A string is basically an array of characters, so you can loop through it:

```js
var str1 = "124590"

function splitMe(str) {
  var arr = []
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    arr.push(str[i]+str[i+1])
    i++
  }
  return arr
}

console.log(splitMe(str1))
console.log(splitMe("1241389572489651"))
```